# MobileFirst Studio 7.0 installation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

Installing IBM MobileFirst Studio 7.0 using MFPF_7.0_ELP_UPD_IBM_MF_STUDIO.zip but due to local LAN security we are not able to get dependency from eclipse market place which are required and downloaded directly from download.eclipse.org org. Where can we download necessary requirements and use this as local repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this .zip file, but I'm pretty sure it is the same: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_studio_plugin_7.0.0.zip

When using the .zip file, you can also attempt the installation with the "Contact all update sites..." checkbox un-checked, before proceeding with the installation in Eclipse.

In general, the MFP Studio installation requires an outside Internet connection.
Find a location with a working connection, install. Make a copy of your Eclipse for future use.

Answer (score 0):

Standard scenario for this setup is to have a central installation (with Internet connection).  Then archive that specific installation, and then sneakernet it each of the disconnected workstations. You must do this for each type of workstation (Win/OSX/Linux) to be supported. No its not optimal, but does resolve the problem.    Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with your network administrator if they can allow your machine to access to the internet via a proxy server. If this is possible all you need is to configure the network connection in Eclipse to include your proxy server setting. You can see the detail here:
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-net-preferences.htm